# Ruby on Rails performance analysis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I am currently working on my bachelor thesis where I made using Rails. Part of my thesis has to be a performance analysis, that is my last missing step.

I am now on the lookout for libraries/gems that I can use that help me.

The structure of the project is a bit weird in terms rails features, because we do not use a database and have only two controllers that matter, one of which is a [WebsocketRails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/) controller. There is basicly a site that allows to write code, the rails websocket controller receives the code via websocket, does several operations and forwards it (via tcp) to a virtual machine which executes the code. The execution sends small packets back to the websocket controller which analyses them and sends packages (via websocket) back to the browser of the client.

So much for the background information, why this rails project does not use a lot of rails' features.

Ruby version: 2.0

Rails version: 4.0.7

I looked into the standard library Benchmark which I probably could use manually (it failed in my first tests), but gem wise I played around with [method_profiler](https://github.com/change/method_profiler) and wanted to track the websocket controller, but it does only show blank results.

**Clarification**: I want to measure timings for the connection between the rails server and my virtal machine for code execution and stress test the number of websocket connections rails can handle. Main focus is on response timings.

What are the best ways for me to approach this?

Comment: performance analysis is a little vague.  can you update your question to specify what you want to measure?

Comment: one way to do this is to extract the info from the logs using after starting the server `tail -f log/development.log | grep "Completed " > analysis.txt`, then you will have to parse the analysis.txt file and extract info from it.. you will have a lot of **Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 10.5ms)** in this file

Comment: I added the clarification. The rendering timings for views etc are not really what I am looking for.